# What specifically does Jesus make lawful in Qur'an 3:50?

Tags: quran, prophet-isa, surat-al-imran

Referring to the [Prophet Isa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_Islam) (Jesus):

> And [make him] a messenger to the Children of Israel, [who will say], 'Indeed I have come to you with a sign from your Lord in that I design for you from clay [that which is] like the form of a bird, then I breathe into it and it becomes a bird by permission of Allah . And I cure the blind and the leper, and I give life to the dead - by permission of Allah. **And I inform you of what you eat and what you store in your houses.** Indeed in that is a sign for you, if you are believers.  **And [I have come] confirming what was before me of the Torah and to make lawful for you some of what was forbidden to you.** And I have come to you with a sign from your Lord, so fear Allah and obey me. -- [Qur'an 3:49-50](https://quran.com/3/49)

It's not clear to me what the Qur'an is referring to as being made lawful here.

**Question**: What specifically does Jesus make lawful in Qur'an 3:50?

Online searching uncovers some tafsir:

> ... Thus he made lawful for them fish and birds which had no spikes; it is also said that he made it all lawful for them so that ba‘d ‘some’ means kull ‘all’. ... -- Tafsir al-Jalalayn (sourced from [alTafsir.com](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=3&tAyahNo=50&tDisplay=yes&LanguageId=2))
>
> That is, "I have come to efface and abolish the superstitions of your ignorant people, the hairsplitting of your jurists, the religious austerities of your ascetics and the restrictive additions made in the Law of Allah under the non-Muslim domination; I will make lawful or unlawful for you only those things which Allah has made lawful or unlawful." -- Maududi (sourced from [alim.org](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/MDD/3/50#sdfootnote46sym))

(I didn't find a tafsir at [QTafsir.com](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=539&Itemid=46#2).)

These give a partial answer to the question, but they (seem to) say different things and don't talk about the completeness of their statements.

Comment: I suspect this refers to some of the [613 mitzvot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/613_commandments), such as the ruling that [meat and milk products cannot be eaten together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_and_meat_in_Jewish_law) - Muslims can eat cheeseburgers if the meat is halal, Jews cannot. I haven't come across a text explaining this though.

Comment: About qtafsir this might be because ibn Kathir didn't say much on this topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different opinions on what exactly 'Isa () made lawful!

Imam al-Qurtobi said  in [his tafsir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=922&idto=922&bk_no=48&ID=342) of "to make lawful for you some of what was forbidden to you" refers to food. Some said what 'Isa made lawful are those things which have been prohibited to them due to their sinful acts as quoted by @Honey in verse [6:146](http://legacy.quran.com/6/146)

> And to those who are Jews We prohibited **every animal of uncloven hoof**; and of the **cattle** and **the sheep** We prohibited to them **their fat**, except what adheres to their backs or the entrails or what is joined with bone. [By] that We repaid them for their injustice. And indeed, We are truthful.

like the fat and animals with uncloven hoofs. Others said he () made lawful things which have been made or declared as unlawful by their priests (and was not unlawful in the Torah). He also quoted Qatadah who said that 'Isa's shari'a was softer than the one of Musa() because Musa prohibited them the camel and some fo the fats and 'Isa made them lawful again.

Az-Zamakhsahri in his [al-Kashaf](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=204&surano=3&ayano=50) said:

> وما حرم الله عليهم في شريعة موسى: الشحوم والثروب ولحوم الإبل، والسمك، وكل ذي ظفر، فأحل لهم عيسى بعض ذلك، قيل: أحل لهم من السمك والطير ما لا صيصية له، واختلفوا في إحلاله لهم السبت،
>   ( - My own translation take it carefully - )
>   And what Allah has made unlawful in the shari'a of Musa was: the fats, the omenta, the flesh of camel, fish and all animals with claws. 'Isa then made lawful some of them, it was said that he made lawful fish, birds which have no spur, there was a dispute whether he has made lawful the Saturday (sabat) or not.

Ibn Kathir only said that this statement shows that the shari'a of 'Isa () abrogated some of the shari'a of Musa () and the dispute among scholars who affirm this with those who said he only made points clear where the Jews were in dispute of based on ([43:63](http://legacy.quran.com/43/63)).

Answer (score 2):

And to those who are Jews We prohibited (because of their sins) every animal of uncloven hoof; and of the cattle and the sheep We prohibited to them their fat, except what adheres to their backs or the entrails or what is joined with bone. [By] that We repaid them for their injustice. And indeed, We are truthful.

https://quran.com/6/146

(FYI in Quran, the Jews are referred *الذین هادوا*)

Answer (score 0):

Jesus made Lawful the Sabbath by Abrogation and working on the Sabbath also even healing   “For the Son of Man is Lord of the sabbath” (Mt 12:8)
Allah finished the abrogation with the Qur'an and abrogating the Sabbath and making foods lawful that was unlawful because of the Jews hindering people from God.

Wherefore for the iniquity of those who are Jews did We disallow to them the good things which had been made lawful for them and for their hindering many (people) from Allah's way. Quran 4:160